# Matplotlib demo code not working

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to run demo code from Matplotlib: the [legend_picking example](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/event_handling/legend_picking.html).

This code is supposed to hide and show plot lines when the legend is clicked.

It seems that event 'pick_event' is not fired when I click on the line on the legend.
I have no problem with the [simple picking example](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/event_handling.html)

```
"""
# Enable picking on the legend to toggle the legended line on and off
"""
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = np.arange(0.0, 0.2, 0.1)
y1 = 2*np.sin(2*np.pi*t)
y2 = 4*np.sin(2*np.pi*2*t)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_title('Click on legend line to toggle line on/off')
line1, = ax.plot(t, y1, lw=2, color='red', label='1 HZ')
line2, = ax.plot(t, y2, lw=2, color='blue', label='2 HZ')
leg = ax.legend(loc='upper left', fancybox=True, shadow=True)
leg.get_frame().set_alpha(0.4)


# we will set up a dict mapping legend line to orig line, and enable
# picking on the legend line
lines = [line1, line2]
lined = dict()
for legline, origline in zip(leg.get_lines(), lines):
    legline.set_picker(5)  # 5 pts tolerance
    lined[legline] = origline


def onpick(event):
    # on the pick event, find the orig line corresponding to the
    # legend proxy line, and toggle the visibilit
    legline = event.artist
    origline = lined[legline]
    vis = not origline.get_visible()
    origline.set_visible(vis)
    # Change the alpha on the line in the legend so we can see what lines
    # have been toggled
    if vis:
        legline.set_alpha(1.0)
    else:
        legline.set_alpha(0.2)
    fig.canvas.draw()

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Does it give any error message? For me it works (Matplotlib 1.0.1).

Comment: There is no message whatsoever... I am able to fire an event handler when I click on lines directly on the plot though. Maybe I do not map well the correspondance between the legend line and the plot line. I'm running it in Mint Linux in VirtualBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of `matplotlib` are you running? Works just fine for me (version `1.1.0`). There are multiple examples on the sourceforge site which do not work for versions below `1.0`. To find out the version number, use

```
import matplotlib
print matplotlib.__version__
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm running version 0.99.3. I'm going to upgrade and will let you know.

Comment: I upgraded to 1.1.0. It works ! For some reason 0.99.3 is the latest available on Mint Linux. I had to rebuild thepackage from sources, losing the backend in the process. After wasting a few hours I am ready to go. Thank you Zhenya.

Answer (score 0):

It does work. Just click on the lines in the legend.

The script is supposed to toggle transparency of the graphs, by clicking on their lines in the legend.

Comment: I am clicking on the lines on the legend. And it doesn't work for me..  And I aim pretty well.

Comment: If you want the picker to react on the lines of the graph, add "picker=5" (or any number>0) in the lines declaration. For example: `line1, = ax.plot(t, y1, lw=2, color='red', label='1 HZ', picker=5)`. But then you'll need to change the handler code.

Comment: Yes, I have no problem clicking on the plot lines directly. Ths only problem is that when the line is invisible you don't know where to click to bring it back...